# How to achieve the recessed text style as in Apple's Messages for Mac?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I'd like to replicate the recessed text style of Messages/iMessage, or, the text "white-shadow" style on a light gray background.

[image: example]

As you can see, the texts are with "white-shadow" even on the light gray background. The bold texts do have subpixel rendering while the gray texts don't (by design?).

I've tried `-setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleRaised` . However it was generating shadows darker than the background. `-setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleLowered` was worse that it even overrode my font colour setting.

So, what is the right way to do this? Any tricks or just have to subclass `NSTextFields`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

The most simplest solution which I can think is to write two texts on each other (For example gray on top and white with difference 1px at bottom).

---

**Solution 2:**

And of course it can be done by subclassing `NSTextFieldCell` and adding shadow.

**Just like this:**

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [shadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0,-1)];
    [shadow setShadowColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius:0];

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    [paragStyle setAlignment:[self alignment]];

    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [self font],NSFontAttributeName,
                      shadow,NSShadowAttributeName,
                      [self textColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                      paragStyle,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,nil];
    [shadow release];
    [paragStyle release];

    NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self stringValue] attributes:attributes];
    [self setAttributedStringValue:string];
    [string release];
    [[self attributedStringValue] drawInRect:cellFrame];
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Text example]